# GNSMessages build issue

Tags: ios, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am using google-nearby pods in my swift project for nearby beacons detection. It works fine. I am able to implement and detect nearby beacons. When I try to make an archive of my application, here comes the issue.

Archive is unable to upload or make build. I have tried everything on SO but unable to sort it out. If someone came through the same issue, any help will be highly appreciated

[image].

Answer (score 0):

After two days headache, finally fixed it. I updated my cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then, updated pod of my project

```
pod update
```

This fixed the issue.